# How to use PySpark to get certain durations?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have already defined the DataFrame below in PySpark. And, how to use PySpark to get the duration (in mins) between the first biking event and the driving event (till the next driving event)?  (Save the results into dataframe, including start_time, start_event, end_time, end_event, and durations, etc)

Notes: there can be other events between biking and driving, such as a person can start from biking, running then driving.

For example, the duration between the first biking event and the coming driving event is:

Start time: the Event should be 'biking' and Action should be 'start'

End time: the Event should be 'driving' and Action should be 'end'

so the duration in date '3/01/2018' is :   8:12 - 5:12 = 3 hours = 180 mins

('start_time' -> timestamp happen at: 3/1/2018 5:12  & 'end_time' -> timestamp happen at: 3/1/2018 8:12)

Notes: there can be multiple biking events then driving events coming, only need to record the first biking event till the next driving event.

the duration for date '3/02/2018' is:  14:12 (driving end as the end time) - 9:12 (first biking start as the start time) = 14:12 - 9:12 = 5 hours = 300 mins

|  | TimeDetails | Event | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/1/2018 5:12 | Biking | start |
| 2 | 3/1/2018 6:12 | Biking | end |
| 3 | 3/1/2018 7:12 | Driving | start |
| 4 | 3/1/2018 8:12 | Driving | end |
| 5 | 3/2/2018 9:12 | Biking | start |
| 6 | 3/2/2018 10:12 | Biking | end |
| 7 | 3/2/2018 11:12 | Biking | start |
| 8 | 3/2/2018 12:12 | Biking | end |
| 9 | 3/2/2018 13:12 | Driving | start |
| 9 | 3/2/2018 14:12 | Driving | end |

Below is some of my code:

```
biking_df = df.filter(df.Event == 'Biking' & (df.Action == 'start'))
driving_df = df.filter(df.Event == 'Driving' & (df.Action == 'end'))
```

Can someone please provide me with some code in PySpark?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to identify and select the relevant rows that contain the start and end times of your durations. With a `Window` function and `lag` you can then get the dates into the same rows and compute the durations:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

time_order_window = Window.orderBy('TimeDetails')

(
    df
    .withColumn('previous_event', F.lag('Event').over(time_order_window)
    .where(
        (F.col('Event') == 'Driving' & F.col('Action') == 'end') |
        (F.col('Event') == 'Biking' & F.col('previous_event') == 'Driving')
    )
    .withColumn('previous_time', F.lag('TimeDetails').over(time_order_window))
    .withColumn('duration_in_sec', (F.col('TimeDetails').cast('double') - F.col('previous_time').cast('double')))
    .withColumn('duration_in_min', F.col('duration_in_sec') / 60
    .where(F.col('Event') == 'Driving')
)
```

This assumes that there is always only one driving event (two rows) between one or several biking events.

Comment: thanks for the help. However, not sure how to show the outputs. It seems like your code partially starts with ( ) after the orderBy statements. Can you please explain a little bit? thank you

Comment: On the other hand, It seems like your code did not work out if there are other events between biking and driving. For example, a person can start from biking, running then driving.  Meawhile, I have updated the question statement, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: For your first comment: if you do not know how to show the outputs, please go through some Spark tutorial to learn the basics - this is not the place for such things.
To your second comment: of course, my code does not cover other events like "running", because you didn't mention them in your question.

Comment: You can simply filter out "Running" events if you are not interested in them.